# Angular, ng-valid by default

Tags: angularjs

I have an issue with the form validation, it is not performed at the form rendering

As you can see in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/o05M8Wd62UnISK9n8I36?p=preview) the form is valid by default (the checking is not run), but if you write something in the box and delete it, it starts working fine (the ok button is disabled).

Does someone know how to setup the form with an invalid state at startup?

Comment: there is some problem with your directive try  <input type="text" ng-model="bar" required/> and it shall work

Comment: I do not want to use the html5 required tag

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `$pristine` property. `$pristine` is set to true if no one touch the form yet.

```
<input type="button" value="ok" ng-disabled="Form.$invalid || Form.$pristine"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the angular way to do that is to use the required attribute.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="bar" required/>
```

You can see on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t1vhgm9v/)

Comment: But if you inspect the element in your example, it loads with the class .ng-invalid already. If you have a css to mark the input red (suggested in the docs), the form loads already red. This feels like a stupid UX, and unfortunately is Angular s default.